# Unable to get correct response from the Json in Android

Tags: php, android, json

I am making a system where I have been interacting with a php script. The php script is used to add records to the mysqli database. I am facing a problem with responding to the Json with android.
Here is my android code.

```
inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
        bufferedReader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String temp;// = null;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder  = new StringBuilder();
        while((temp = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null) {
            stringBuilder.append(temp);
        }
        String jsonbuilded = stringBuilder.toString();
        Log.i("jsonbuilded string: ",jsonbuilded);
        JSONObject recievedJsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonbuilded);//Line number 114
        String recievedString = recievedJsonObject.getString("result");
            Log.i("String Recieved",recievedString);
        if(recievedString.compareTo("1")==0){
            runOnthisUIThread("Your query has been successfully placed.");
        }
        else if(recievedString.compareTo("2")==0){
            runOnthisUIThread("The payment of Client "+ params[1] + " is already done by "+params[2]);
        }
        else if(recievedString.compareTo("5")==0){
            Log.i("Entry: ",params[0]);
            runOnthisUIThread("Records not found. Please try again later.");
        }
        else if(recievedString.compareTo("4")==0){
            String employ_assoc = recievedJsonObject.getString("name");
            runOnthisUIThread("The payment is already done by "+ employ_assoc);
        }
        else{
            runOnthisUIThread("Unknown Runtime Error... Kindly contact the Developers.");

        }
```

The `runOnthisUIThread()` is a function which will display the Toast.

And here is my relevant code snippet from php.

```
if ($query->num_rows >0)
{
  $query_result = $query->fetch_assoc();
  $id = $query_result['ID'];
  if(!$this->con)
  {
    $resultOfQuery['result'] = '0'; //connection not successfully
    die(json_encode(resultOfQuery));
  }
  else
  {
    $queryforcalc = "SELECT * FROM `".$clientid."` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
    $queryforcalcresult = $this->con_user->query($queryforcalc);
    if($queryforcalcresult->num_rows >0)
    {
      $query_calc_rawdata = $queryforcalcresult->fetch_assoc();
      //echo $query_calc_rawdata;
      //This section is for calculation of meter readings.
      $lastmeterreadings = $query_calc_rawdata['meter_readings'];
      $meter_readings = $meter_readings - $lastmeterreadings;
    }
        if($meter_readings > 0)
        {
          $timestamp = $this->string->getCurrentTimeStamp();
          $update_user_table = "INSERT INTO `".DATABASE_USER."`.`$clientid` (`timestamp`, `meter_readings`) VALUES ('$timestamp', '$meter_readings');";
          $this->con_user->query($update_user_table);
          //echo $this->con_user->query($update_user_table);
          //echo $this->con->query($update_query);
          $update_query = "UPDATE `".DATABASE."`.`client_list` SET `Meter_readings` = '$meter_readings', `bool` = '1', `Employ_Assoc` = '$employid' WHERE `client_list`.`ID` = '$clientid';";
          //echo $update_query;
          $this->con->query($update_query);
          //echo $this->con;
          $resultOfQuery['result'] = '1'; // successfully placed
          die(json_encode($resultOfQuery));
        }
        else
        {
          $resultOfQuery['result'] = '2';// Invalid entry of meter readings
          die(json_encode($resultOfQuery));
        }

      }
  }
else
{
  $query_statment = "SELECT * FROM client_list WHERE ID = '{$clientid}' AND bool = '1'";
  $queryresultofsecondphase = $this->con->query($query_statment);
  if($queryresultofsecondphase->num_rows >0)
  {
    $queryResult = $queryresultofsecondphase->fetch_assoc();
    $employname = $queryResult['Employ_Assoc'];
    echo $employname;
    $resultOfQuery['result'] = '4';//Record already excists.
    $resultOfQuery['name'] = $employname;
    die(json_encode($resultOfQuery));
  }
  else
  {
    $resultOfQuery['result']= '5';//Record not found. The user does not excists.
    die(json_encode($resultOfQuery));
  }
}
}
```

When I return a response '4', I have to send the name as well. And so i used another Json for it tag 'name'. But I get a Json exception. Here is my stack trace.

```
09-01 12:18:14.097  25321-25357/com.ems.employ I/connection successful﹕ [ 09-01 12:18:14.102 25321:25357 I/jsonbuilded string:  ]
0{"result":"4","name":"0"}
09-01 12:18:14.102  25321-25357/com.ems.employ W/System.err﹕ org.json.JSONException: Value 0 of type java.lang.Integer cannot be converted to JSONObject
09-01 12:18:14.102  25321-25357/com.ems.employ W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
09-01 12:18:14.102  25321-25357/com.ems.employ W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:160)
09-01 12:18:14.102  25321-25357/com.ems.employ W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
09-01 12:18:14.102  25321-25357/com.ems.employ W/System.err﹕ at com.ems.employ.authenticatedemploy$SendMeterReadings.doInBackground(authenticatedemploy.java:114)
09-01 12:18:14.102  25321-25357/com.ems.employ W/System.err﹕ at com.ems.employ.authenticatedemploy$SendMeterReadings.doInBackground(authenticatedemploy.java:78)
```

Comment: Getting `0{"result":"4","name":"0"}` in response?

Comment: yea this is the response m getting in android

Comment: means response is invalid need to remove `0` before `{` to make it valid json string

Comment: so how do i do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your JSON response looks wrong, it has "0" at the start: `0{"result":"4","name":"0"}` I think it is because you have uncommented `echo` in your php code: `echo $employname;`

Before parsing your JSON in Android app code I recommend you to try fetch it with regular browser and make sure that JSON is valid, you can use [json lint](http://jsonlint.com/) for this porpuse.